# Minimum initial vertical velocity of a projectile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, projectile

A basketball is launched by a person with an initial velocity $v$ at an angle $\theta $ from a height $L$ into a basket of height $H>L$ which is a horizontal distance $d$ from the person.

Additionally, $H-L=h$

Assumptions:

Zero air resistance and the diameter of the ball $<<$ diameter of the basket.

I am trying to prove:

$$v\sin(\theta) > \sqrt{2gh}$$

What I have done so far:

$$a_x=\ddot{x}=0$$

$$v_x=\dot{x}(t)=v\cos{\theta}$$

$$x(t)=vt\cos{\theta}$$
$$a_y=\ddot{y}=-g$$

$$v_y=\dot{y}(t)=L-gt$$

$$y(t)=L+v\sin(\theta)t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$

Assume the ball reaches the basket at time $t=t_b$

$$x(t_b)=vt_b\cos{\theta}=d \Longrightarrow t_b=\frac{d}{v\cos{\theta}}$$

$$y(t_b)=L+v\sin(\theta)t_b-\frac{1}{2}gt_b^2=H$$

$$H-L=v\sin(\theta)t_b-\frac{1}{2}gt_b^2=h$$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Height_at_x . Use this formula and the right coordinates to calculate $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always start with a picture:

[image]

Horizontal velocity is $v\cos\theta$, so time to reach basket is $\frac{v\cos\theta}{d}$

We need to increase our height by at least $h$ in that time. It is intuitively obvious that the lowest velocity I can get away with is the one that will *just* get into the basket - that is, the ball arrives "horizontally". For the ball to follow the trajectory I drew, with a maximum along the way, it must have been going faster - more vertical velocity to reach a greater height.

If the ball just reaches $h$, then from conservation of energy we know $\frac12 m v_v^2 = m g h$, so the vertical component of velocity must be $v_v=\sqrt{2gh}$.

And the vertical component of velocity is $v_v = v\sin\theta$, so your expression immediately follows.

Answer (score 2):

### If the Ball Never Goes Above $H$

In this case, ***all*** of the ball's initial kinetic energy (due to vertical motion) is converted into potential energy by the time it rises by distance $h$. Then, we have:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Delta K &= \Delta P \\
\frac{1}{2}m(v\sin{\theta})^2 &= mgh \\
v\sin{\theta} &= \sqrt{2gh}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Where $\Delta K$ is the kinetic energy lost to the potential energy gained over distance $h$ and $\Delta P$ is the potential energy gained over the distance $h$.

### If the Ball Goes Above $H$

The ball must go higher than $H$ to enter the basket.

In this case, ***not all*** of the ball's initial kinetic energy (due to vertical motion) is converted to potential energy by the time the ball has traveled over distance $h$. Thus $\frac{1}{2}m(v\sin{\theta})^2$ accounts for additional kinetic energy besides that which equals $mgh$.

So, we let

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
K &= K_h + K_a &= \frac{1}{2}m(v\sin{\theta})^2 \\
P &= P_h + P_a &= (mgh) + P_a \\
K_h &= P_h \\
K_a &= P_a
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where:

- $K$ is the total kinetic energy the ball loses while going up, due to changes in the vertical component of its velocity.
- $P$ is the total potential energy the ball gains while going up.
- Subscript $_h$ refers to quantities corresponding to motion from height $L$ to height $H$, over distance $h$.
- Subscript $_a$ refers to quantities corresponding to motion at heights above $H$.

It follows that:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
K &= P \\
K - K_a &= P - P_a \\
K - K_a &= P_h \\
\frac{1}{2}m(v\sin{\theta})^2 - K_a &= mgh \\
(v\sin{\theta})^2 &= 2gh + \frac{2}{m}K_a\\
v\sin{\theta} &= \sqrt{2gh + \frac{2}{m}K_a}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Since $K_a$ is non-zero in this case, we have:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
v\sin{\theta} &> \sqrt{2gh}
\end{split}
\end{equation}